# Dafny "call may violate context's modifies clause" error using method invocation inside while loop where "fresh" invariant isn't an option

Tags: dafny

Below is a simplified (and so useless) version of a `Queue` class built using linked lists. There is an `Add` method that adds another (fresh) linked list node to the end of the queue. If I write another method taking a `q: Queue` as an argument, and run `q.Add` repeatedly in a while loop, I get a "call may violate context's modifies clause" error that I can't solve using a `fresh` invariant, because `q` may already have nodes allocated. Is there a way handling this situation?

```
class LL {  /* linked list nodes */
  var elem: int;
  var next: LL?;  /* may be null */

  constructor (x: int)
    ensures elem == x && next == null
  {
    elem, next := x, null;
  }
}

class Queue {  // simplified version of queues of integers
  var hd: LL;  // implemented using linked list
  var tl: LL;

  ghost var nodes: seq<LL>;  // nodes of linked list

  predicate invar()  // class invariant (ignores elem's)
    reads this, nodes
  {
      nodes != [] && nodes[0] == hd && nodes[|nodes| - 1] == tl &&
      nodes[|nodes| - 1].next == null &&
      (forall i: nat {:trigger nodes[i].next} ::
         i < |nodes| - 1 ==> nodes[i].next == nodes[i + 1])
  }

  constructor ()  // we start with one node
    ensures invar() && |nodes| == 1 && fresh(nodes)
  {
    var l: LL := new LL(0);
    hd, tl := l, l;
    nodes := [l];
  }

  method Add(d: int)  // add another node
    requires invar()
    ensures invar()
    ensures
      nodes != [] && nodes[.. |nodes| - 1] == old(nodes) &&
      fresh(nodes[|nodes| - 1])
    modifies this, nodes
  {
    var l: LL := new LL(d);
    tl.next := l;
    tl := l;
    nodes := nodes + [l];
  }
}

method Foo(q: Queue)
  // if we assume this:
  //   requires q.nodes == []
  // but we want that q may already have some nodes, to which we will add
  requires q.invar()
  modifies q, q.nodes
{
  var i: nat := 0;
  while (i < 10)
    invariant i <= 10
    invariant q.invar()
    // then adding this fresh invariant works:
    //   invariant fresh(q.nodes)
    decreases 10 - i
  {
    q.Add(i);  // error: "call may violate context's modifies clause"
    i := i + 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have two solutions for you. In the first solution, I tried to make minimal changes to the way you set up your data structures, but at the cost that the solution is somewhat hacky/black-magic-y. In the second solution, I show that you can make the proof much cleaner if you are willing to track an additional ghost variable in the queue data structure. The second solution is also in line with idiomatic Dafny style for building these kinds of heap data structures.

First version of first solution: (not quite right, see below)

```
method Foo(q: Queue)
  requires q.invar()
  modifies q, q.nodes
{
  var i: nat := 0;
  while (i < 10)
    invariant i <= 10
    invariant q.invar()
    invariant forall x :: x in q.nodes ==> x in old(q.nodes) || fresh(x)
    modifies q, q.nodes
    decreases 10 - i
  {
    q.Add(i);
    i := i + 1;
  }
}
```

We know that `q.Add` is allowed to modify any node in the current value of `q.nodes`. To convince Dafny this is safe, we need to maintain the invariant that every element in `q.nodes` is either in the value of `q.nodes` from the beginning of `Foo`, or is fresh since the beginning of `Foo`.

Unfortunately, just this invariant doesn't quite cut it -- Dafny still reports an error on the call to `q.Add`. I actually had to drop down to the Boogie level to debug this problem, and it appeared to me to be a case of an overly restrictive trigger on the new loop invariant, which prevented Dafny from having access to the invariant when trying to prove the call to `q.Add` would not violate the modifies clause.

So I replaced the trigger with the following very aggressive one:

```
invariant forall x {:trigger allocated(x)} :: x in q.nodes ==> x in old(q.nodes) || fresh(x)
```

This causes the quantifier to be available for any allocated reference. This causes the program to verify.

---

Second solution:

The underlying issue here has to do with the encoding of sequences versus sets. When you say that a method can modify a *sequence* of references, that is slightly harder for the underlying solver to reason about than if you say it modifies a *set* of references. So I recommend converting your code to tracking sets of references. Here is one way:

```
class Queue {
  var hd: LL;
  var tl: LL;

  ghost var nodes: seq<LL>;
  ghost var footprint: set<object>  // ***

  predicate invar()
    reads this, nodes
  {
      nodes != [] && nodes[0] == hd && nodes[|nodes| - 1] == tl &&
      nodes[|nodes| - 1].next == null &&
      (forall i: nat {:trigger nodes[i].next} ::
         i < |nodes| - 1 ==> nodes[i].next == nodes[i + 1]) && 
      (forall x :: x in nodes ==> x in footprint)  // ***
  }

  constructor ()
    ensures invar() && |nodes| == 1 && fresh(nodes)  // ***
  {
    var l: LL := new LL(0);
    hd, tl := l, l;
    nodes := [l];
    footprint := {l};  // ***
  }

  method Add(d: int)
    requires invar()
    ensures invar()
    ensures
      nodes != [] && nodes[.. |nodes| - 1] == old(nodes) &&
      fresh(footprint - old(footprint))  // ***
    modifies this, footprint             // ***
  {
    var l: LL := new LL(d);
    tl.next := l;
    tl := l;
    nodes := nodes + [l];
    footprint := footprint + {l};  // ***
  }
}

method Foo(q: Queue)
  requires q.invar()
  modifies q, q.footprint  // ***
{
   var i: nat := 0;
   while (i < 10)
    invariant i <= 10
    invariant q.invar()
    invariant fresh(q.footprint - old(q.footprint))  // ***
    decreases 10 - i
  {
    q.Add(i);
    i := i + 1;
  }
}
```

All changed lines are marked with `// ***`. (The `LL` class does not change at all.)

I track a new ghost variable called `footprint`, which tracks the set of references that are owned by the queue. I adjust all the modifies clauses to use the set rather than the sequence, and I update the class invariant (often called `Valid` in idiomatic Dafny) to ensure that the `footprint` contains all the nodes. I also adjust the constructor and `Add` to update the footprint as appropriate.

In particular, the postcondition for `Add` now includes the clause `fresh(footprint - old(footprint))`. This is extremely idiomatic of mutator methods in imperative heap datastructures in Dafny. It says that `Add` does not secretly stash any references into footprint except those that are freshly allocated since the beginning of this call to `Add`.

Then, in `Foo`, we can rephrase the loop invariant to the similar `fresh(q.footprint - old(q.footprint))`. Dafny no longer needs any additional strange triggers to see that the body of the loop is now safe.

---

For more information, see sections 0 and 1 of [Specification and Verification of Object-Oriented Software](http://leino.science/papers/krml190.pdf). (Note that this paper is quite old now, so some minor things are out of date. But the key ideas are there. Someone has tried to port it to modern Dafny [here](https://github.com/zhuzilin/dafny-exercises/blob/main/paper/krml190.dfy), but I can't vouch for the code quality or accuracy.)

Comment: Excellent to know about the difference between sequences and set in this respect. I tried something like your first solution, but failed.

Comment: If this is of any help still, my implementation of a FIFO queue from the same paper is here: https://github.com/CodeNinja89/dafnyPractice/blob/main/LinkedQueue_krml.dfy

Comment: @JamesWilcox, based on your answer, I tried implementing insert at a given position in a list. The verification fails because the verifier is unable to prove: `forall i: nat :: i < |nodes| - 1 ==> nodes[i].next == nodes[i + 1]`. It would be great if you could shed some light on this. My implementation can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/CodeNinja89/e44e2291ce14eae1dd4cb9e4b45f10f8)

Comment: @DronaNagarajan I would recommend asking a separate question about that. You can link to this thread for context. (It is very difficult to have meaningful discussions about follow-on issues in the comments, because stack exchange comments are limited.)

Comment: @JamesWilcox I have posted the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78052155/inserting-a-node-at-a-random-position-in-a-linked-list-dafny).